# Apache Camel: aggregate on pollEnrich results rather than from and how to preserve headers

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

In my camel route I consume messages from a queue; Each message contains headers "pad" (the path) and a file prefix. E.g.:

message1: pad="/some/dir", file="AAA"
message2: pad="/another/dir", file="BRD"

Per message I want a file created:
message1: /some/dir/AAA.tar (containing all files /some/dir/AAA*)
message2: /another/dir/BRD.tar (containing all files in /another/dir/BRD.tar)

The directories and filenames are collected in another route.

so far I have this camel route:

```
from("broker1:files.queue")
.log("starting with message ${header.file}")
.pollEnrich()
    .simple("file:${header.pad}?antInclude=${header.file}.*")
.aggregate(new TarAggregationStrategy(false,true))
     .constant(true)
     .completionFromBatchConsumer()
     .eagerCheckCompletion()
     .parallelProcessing(false)
     .setHeader("file", simple("${header.file}"))
     .setHeader("pad", simple("${header.pad}"))
.log("tarring to: ${header.pad}${header.file}.tar")
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${header.file}.tar"))
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH, simple("${header.pad}"))
.to("file://ignored")
.log("Going to do other stuff here on ${header.file}");
```

I have a few issues here:
- When running this route, I see multiple "starting with message" lines before I see a log line "tarring to"
- the log line "tarring to" actually says ".tar", the headers are empty...
- The ".tar" file created is stored in "./ignored" and contains one file from each jms message file header.

This leads me to believe the aggregation happens on a level I am not expecting; I want to aggregate the results of the pollEnrich, not of the other messages on the queue. Why, and how can I make it behave as I want?

The other is the lost headers; It might be due to the aggregation on the wrong items... Anyway, I would think that the setHeader()s in the aggregation should set them, but they're lost anyway; How can I preserve them?

I'm relatively new to camel programming; so please forgive my shortcomings; The indentation in the code is how I *think* the scope should be; Which probably is totally off. I am using camel-2.20.1, but can switch to any other version.

**Edit**
That reading made me change the route a bit; as written in the comments; it now looks like this: (the TarAggregationStrategy() is created in my CamelContext and there added to the registry)

```
from("broker1:files.queue")
.log("starting with message ${header.file}")
.pollEnrich()
    .simple("file:${header.pad}?antInclude=${header.file}.*")
    .aggregationStrategyRef("tarAggregationStrategy")
.log("tarring to: ${header.pad}${header.file}.tar")
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, simple("${header.file}.tar"))
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_PATH, simple("${header.pad}"))
.to("file://ignored")
.log("Going to do other stuff here on ${header.file}");
```

It does seem to go better now; with the exception that the actual tar does not occur due to not being able to create a temp file as per the stack trace:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Could not make temp file (c9db039a-1585-4e63-85dc-e21ca268b290)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.tarfile.TarAggregationStrategy.aggregate(TarAggregationStrategy.java:174)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.PollEnricher.process(PollEnricher.java:280)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not make temp file (c9db039a-1585-4e63-85dc-e21ca268b290)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.tarfile.TarAggregationStrategy.addFileToTar(TarAggregationStrategy.java:199)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.tarfile.TarAggregationStrategy.aggregate(TarAggregationStrategy.java:167)
        ... 19 more
```

The thing that I noticed is that the part between ( and ) after Could not create temp file is actually the content of the body (which I could've left empty, but for no apparent reason I filled with the file id)

Comment: Study the poll enrich EIP patterns docs some more to find examples how you can use aggregation strategy directly with this EIP pattern without having to add aggregate EIP as well.

Comment: Thanks; that does unstuck me; now using pollEnrich().simple("...").aggregationStrategyRef("myTarRef"); This seems to get things moving, however I now get an error "Could not make temp file (<body of the inbound jms message>)". Which I don't understand, what exactly is going wrong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve headers from your messages so that they still exist after aggregation, your **aggregation strategy** has to do this. I do not think that `TarAggregationStrategy` does this.

Think of the aggregator as a boundary. It collects Camel Exchanges (Camel-wrapped Messages) and creates a **new** Exchange according to the `AggregationStrategy`. I guess that most out-of-the-box aggregators focus on merging or appending message bodies but not headers.

So if you want your headers `header.file` and `header.pad` to survive the aggregation, you have to implement that in your own aggregation strategy.

Since you use `TarAggregationStrategy` you could probably extend or decorate this one, just implement the header stuff and delegate to `TarAggregationStrategy` for the body stuff.

Comment: Thanks; doing just that right now; weekend is incoming, so doubt I have much time to work on this one till monday. Got a bit further with figuring the headers of the old and new exchanges, and think I can preserve them. No clue on the tempfile exception I am getting; will give it a good ponder as well.

Comment: I had it working somewhat at some point; kinda lost where... Now I get a bit confused about pollEnrich and batches. When I read the internet, I see something about pollEnrich() polls one file at a time; but... I have at least 2 and probably at most 10 files per message that should be in the collection. On the other hand, I see statements that `file2` would be a batchConsumer and I should get all the files; Also, I notice a difference in behavior when I use pollEnrich()...aggregationStrategy() and pollEnrich()....aggregate(); what is the difference?

Comment: Rather than use pollEnrich() along with aggregation, I decided to remove that complexity and just simpy use a Processor and move along. The processor just takes the headers and creates a tar with `TarArchiveOutputStream`. Much easier that way.

Comment: You could also remove complexity by splitting your route. For example just use the JMS message as trigger to move the needed files to another directory. Then use another route with a normal file poller to tar the files. But then you would need to make sure that no other files arrive while the files of one message are moved and tar-ed. So there is complexity too.

Comment: Thanks for that remark; well, the point is that this route is part of a greater context. The current solution works perfectly, although I think I can combine a few routes into one. Yet I like how each step is decoupled. My first route does a query on a database getting a bunch of ids, then those files get downloaded from a nosql database, the first database gets a flag that the files are downloaded and ready to be moved into a single tar, which is what this route does: get the ids from the database and process them. Given that I need to work on millions of files this one is fun.